# Solve the recurrence relation $T(n) = (n-1) T(n-1)$

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

How do I resolve the following recurrence relation?

> - $T(n) = (n-1) T(n-1),$
> - $T(1) = 1.$

My reasoning:

> $T(n) = T(n-1-k)(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\cdots(n-k)$
>
> $k = n$  $\leftarrow$  yields the base case
>
> $T(n) = T(1)\cdot n!$
>   $T(n) = n!$

In terms of Big O complexity, this would be:

> $T(n) = O(n!)$

This question, inspired from:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52710864/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-this-5-line-java-algorithm

claims the answer is **double** factorial: $O(n) = n!!$

How so?

Comment: Actually $T(n)=(n-1)!$.

Comment: Okay; though, I am more interested in the big O complexity, so I don't really care much about constants

Comment: You copied the recurrence wrong, that post says $T(n) = (n-1)T(n-2)$.

Comment: That question is about $(n-1)T(n-2)$, unlike your question.

Comment: Yes, I didn't copy it exactly. But, with respect to the big O notation, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: The recurrence in that answer is $T(n)=(n-1)T(n-{\color{red}2})$ instead of $T(n)=(n-1)T(n-{\color{red}1})$...

Comment: If you think it doesn't matter then you think $n!$ and $n!!$ are the same and your question is empty

Comment: How could (n-1)T(n-2) be n!!, and (n-1)T(n-1) be n! ....??

Comment: this second one in your comment is also not the same, there are now 3 different recursions......

Comment: note that $n!!\le n!$. see [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)

Comment: Wow!! Thank you farruhota -- I didn't know what double factorial actually meant! Post that as an answer and I will accdpt

Comment: Also -- to all the downvoters -- remember that I said the question was "inspired" by the one in that link, and indeed it was -- I never claimed to copy it directly

Answer (score -1):

You can use Stirling's approximation

$n!=nlogn - n$

to show that

$n!=n^n*1/e^n$

So, $n!=O(n^n)$